# Can you add an indent inside a p element?

Tags: html, css

Can you add an indent within a p element? I keep adding spaces between words but only one space is added. I do not want to create a new line with a br tag but rather multiple spaces between words.

Ex:

[image]

Comment: Can you share code for what you have tried so far?

Comment: Hey Jack. Why don't you simply create a table and hide the grid lines? Would be way more efficient.

Comment: well it's not an indent but your space thing you can use `&nbsp;` though this is not how you should handle whatever you're doing https://codepen.io/anon/pen/maQoPG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with `white-space:pre-wrap;`

```css
p {
  white-space:pre-wrap;
}
```

```html
<p>a              b                                       c</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

Concerning your demand: I would suggest you to create a table with hidden grid lines:

```css
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

td {
  width: 33%;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<table cellspacing="10">
  <tr>
    <td>McNair Scholar</td>
    <td>Member</td>
    <td>Spring 2017-Present</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Code2040 Fellow</td>
    <td>Fellow</td>
    <td>Summer 2017</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What makes you think it screws up the accessibility? The content is plainly tabular. A table is completely the appropriate choice for accessibility.

Answer (score 1):

`p` elements are meant for paragraphs. Your example is definitely not a paragraph so you'll need to use other elements to assemble it.

There are several ways to do what your asking. One of those ways is:

```css
.grid {
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50% 25% 25%;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div>McNair Scholar</div><div>Member</div><div>Spring 2017-Present</div>
  <div>Code2040 Fellow</div><div>Fellow</div><div>Summer 2017</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Better way than mine! :)

Comment: `<div>` elements are generic blocks, they really should be used only as a last resort if there are no elements with appropriate semantics. A table is the better option here.

Comment: @Quentin So your issue is that divs aren't semantic enough but want to trade them for something whose semantics are wrong for the situation. If it's tabular content, sure, use a table. If it isn't, then don't.

Comment: @Ouroborus — The content looks tabular. `<th>Position</th><th>Rank</th><th>Time period</th></tr>`

Comment: @Quentin I think it's unclear. The example may coincidentally look tabular but the context in which the example is provided implies that the need is for layout. Then there's the meta game: I know people are going to go for the traditional/easy answers. I said there are several ways of doing it of which this is one and I tried not to imply that my answer was the One True Answer.

Answer (score 0):

Sandwich your text in the `<pre></pre>` tag and include the spaces/indents normally.

```html
<pre>McNair Scholar           Member          Spring 2017-Present</pre>
<pre>Code2040 Fellow          Fellow          Summer 2017</pre>
```

Comment: Hope you don't use characters for elements styles in your career

Comment: I don't follow. What exactly was wrong with using &nbsp;?

Comment: `&nbsp;` is an entity for the unicode character "non-breaking space". It's meant for situations where you would otherwise use a space but do not want a line break to appear at that location in the text. It's not meant to be used as a means to override collapsing white-space; instead use `<pre>` or CSS for that.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll edit my answer. And remove that option